# org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter doesn't have the setAlwaysUseFullPath method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am migrating from spring 4 to spring 5. In spring 4, `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` is deprecated in favor of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. However, the method `setAlwaysUseFullPath` is missing in `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. How can I achieve the same result with `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.html).

> Supports direct matches (given "/test" -> registered "/test") and "*" matches (given "/test" -> registered "/t*"). Note that the default is to map within the current servlet mapping if applicable; see the "alwaysUseFullPath" property for details. For details on the pattern options, see the AntPathMatcher javadoc.

```
    @Bean
    BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping beanNameUrlHandlerMapping() {
        BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping beanNameUrlHandlerMapping = new BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping();
        beanNameUrlHandlerMapping.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);
        return new BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping();
    }
```

use sample code: [Guide to Spring Handler Mappings](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-handler-mappings#beannameurlhandlermapping)